# Finding a vowel or a consonant

Tags: python

I looked it up and I have to use it like this:

```
letter = input ("Enter  a letter: ")
if letter == "a" or letter  == "e" or letter == "i" or letter  == "o" or letter == "u":
print ("It's  a vowel.")
```

But why I can I not use it like this?  When I do this, and enter "a", nothing gets printed. I can do this with numbers.

```
vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

userinput = str(input("Enter a letter of the alphabet: "))

if userinput == vowel:
    print("You have entered a vowel")
```

Comment: `userinput` isn't a `list`, so it will never _equal_ `vowel`.  You want `if userinput in vowel:`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what your looking for is this :

```
vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

userinput = str(input("Enter a letter of the alphabet: ").lower())

if userinput in vowel:
    print("You have entered a vowel")
else:
    print('not a vowel')
```

**Reason why code didn't work:**
Since vowel is a list, you need to use the statement `if userinput in vowel` rather than `if userinput == vowel:`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you!  So the problem was I had not entered the "else" statement?

Comment: No , the problem was : Since vowel is a list, you need to use the statement `if userinput in vowel` rather than `if userinput == vowel:`

Comment: question more to the OP - what happens if user enters an `A`?

Comment: Ok.  I have never used the "in" before.  Thank you.

Comment: @rv.kvetch edited the ans, by adding .lower() function, using it we can solve the issue of capital letters, btw Modo can you accept the ans, thank you

Comment: @tyzion well I wanted to clarify with the OP first about how he'd expect to handle that scenario, however it's great that you were thinking ahead of me ;)

Comment: @rv.kvetch I didn't know.  The .lower() is also something new I learned.  Also, it tells me that is a consonant if I enter a number even though I have put in str.  I thought it would be restricted to letters only.